# $L^1$ convergence of a stopped, uniformly bounded random variable

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

The question was at the end of my professor's notes for a graduate probability class, and I'm trying to solve it to prepare myself for the midterm.

> Suppose that $X_n \rightarrow X_\infty$ in $L^1$, $\{X_n: n=1,2,\cdots\}$ is  uniformly bounded, and that S is a random variable taking values in $\{0,1,2,\cdots,\infty\}$. Then $X_{n\wedge S}\rightarrow X_S$ in $L^1$.

In the notes, there is the following hint:

> For each subsequence $\{X_{{n_j}\wedge S}\}$, choose a further subsequence $\{X_{{n_{j_k}}\wedge S}\}$ such that $X_{n_{j_k}} \rightarrow X_\infty$ almost surely.

Here is my current work, which I hope is correct:

> We need to show that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}[X_{S\wedge n}(\omega)] = \mathbb{E}[X_S(\omega)]$. Since $X_n$ converges in $L^1$, it also converges in probability, and therefore for each subsequence $\{X_{n_j \wedge S}\},$ we can choose a further subsequence $\{X_{n_{j_k}\wedge S}\}$ such that $X_{n_{j_k}} \rightarrow X_\infty$ almost surely.
>
> Since $|X_n| < K$ for all $n, \omega \in \Omega$, $|X_{n\wedge
>  S}(\omega)| < K$, so we can apply the DCT:$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow
>  \infty}\int_{\Omega} X_{S \wedge n}(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega) =
>  \int_{\Omega}\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_{S\wedge
>  n}(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = \int_{\Omega}X_S (\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega).$$

Comment: The idea is good, but the details are not correct yet. Try to write down a proper proof by contradiction. In your current proof you use in the last line that $X_{S\wedge n}\to X_s$ which you just know to be true for a subsequence. Also showing that the expectations converge is not the same as showing that something converges in $L^1$.

Comment: Is S a stopping time or not necessarily?

Comment: It is a random variable taking values in $\{0,1,2,\cdots,\infty\}$ as written in the question.